# c++ socket client implementation

Tags: c++, node.js, sockets

I have maybe a strange problem, but I can't get sockets working. I need to connect c++ app with node.js server, which has open socket. I have tried many sources, but none of them are working. One of that, that I have at the moment:

```
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "3000"

int sock()
{
    int argc = 2;
    const char* argv[3];
    argv[0] = "127.0.0.1";
    argv[1] = "127.0.0.1";
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo* result = NULL,
        * ptr = NULL,
        hints;
    const char* sendbuf = "this is a test";
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Validate the parameters
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

    // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
    iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

    } while (iResult > 0);

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

This is official microsoft code for the winsock client. Also, I have tried socket client code from here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/

From the microsoft code I am getting that, data was sent, but node.js console remains empty: https://prnt.sc/zdhpsi

Node.js server code:

```
var port = 3000;

var io = require('socket.io')().listen(port);
console.log("Listening on port " + port);

/* Socket.IO events */
io.on("connection", function(socket){
    console.log("new connection");
    socket.on('test_text', (...args) => {
        console.log("test text event received.", args);
    });

    socket.on('test_binary', (...args) => {
        console.log("test binary event received", args);
      if(args[0] instanceof Buffer)
      {
        console.log("test binary event received,binary length:"+ args[0].length);
      }
    });

    socket.on('test ack',function()
    {
       var args =Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
      if('object' == typeof args[0])
      {
        console.log("test combo received,object:");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(args[0]));
      }
      if(args.length>1 && 'function' == typeof args[args.length - 1])
      {
        console.log('need ack for test combo');
        var fn = args[args.length - 1];
        fn('Got bin length:' + args[0].bin.length);//invoke ack callback function.
      }
    });

  });
```

On c++ side I don't need to recieve anything, I just need to send the data
Maybe you know how this could be done? Thanks :)

Comment: You said it doesn't work, but have you figured out which part of your code isn't working?

Comment: Well... I supose that it's c++ part

Comment: I assumed that, but you have `printf` lines that should be getting hit if there's an error.  What's printed to your console?

Comment: @StephenNewell Like I said. It seems that, it is being sent https://prnt.sc/zdlnkh

Comment: Looks like the C++ side is working fine then, at least at the raw socket level; you can verify with Wireshark if you want to be sure, but no errors are being reported.  Add some extra debugging to the nodejs side?  Your C++ code is getting something sent back, so print that and try to figure out what path is being hit on your node js side?

Comment: @StephenNewell Interresting... Wireshark is empty. There are no packets sent. But program shows that they are - https://prnt.sc/zdn91s